# Is it possible to decode HTML using lynx, in a Python script?

Tags: python, subprocess, lynx

Let the `html` variable be a string containing the whole source code of a webpage, e.g.

```
html = "<!doctype html>\n<html><head><title>My title</title></head>LOTS OF CHARS HERE</html>"
```

I would like to `print` this web page in a human-readable format, using `lynx` if possible. I tried various things along the lines of

```
print(subprocess.run(['echo', html, '|', 'lynx', '-stdin', '-dump'], capture_output=True, text=True).stdout)
```

or

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(["echo", html], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(subprocess.run(['lynx', '-stdin', '-dump'], stdin=p1.stdout, capture_output=True, text=True).stdout)
```

but it fails with the following error

> OSError: [Errno 7] Argument list too long: 'echo'

Any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for `echo`, use `html` as the `input` for `lynx`.

```
print(subprocess.run(['lynx', '-stdin', '-dump'], input=html, capture_output=True, text=True).stdout)
```

Comment: Nice; I didn't realize that `subprocess.run` allowed a literal string to be passed to `input` now.